# as3: fastest method to search next higher/lower value in unsorted array?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

how to deal with unsorted arrays to get the next higher or next smaller value?

```
var _myArray:Array = (1,pizza,2,6,8,test,11,16,17,cola)

    _myArray.splice(4,1) // > remove number 8 !

trace(_myArray) // > array contains now: (1,pizza,2,6,test,11,16,17,cola)
```

**how can i get the next higher value (= 11) ?**

Comment: do you have to leave it unsorted before finding the value? If not, sort it then just do 1 index higher than what you chose first.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers and Strings in the same array?

Comment: unfortunately i must storage this kind of data (several k) only for a few seconds, my current function takes 3029ms..

Comment: how large is your array?  Or the largest it will ever get?

Comment: sometimes just 20, sometimes 10k

Comment: are pizza, test, and cola all numbers/ints?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could just paste your current algorithm in here. It would make thinking about it easier and we wouldn't have to make any assumptions about your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use sorting, even if your array has to remain in the same unsorted state for some reason.  And I'll bet using Flash's native sorting methods will be way faster than creating your own.  You will, though, have to traverse the entire array once:

```
var sortedArray : Array  = [];

for ( var i:int = 0; i < _myArray.length; i++) {
    var o:Object = _myArray[i];
    // use only int values for sorting:
    if (o is int) sortedArray.push ({index:i, value:o});   
}
sortedArray.sortOn ("value", Array.NUMERIC);
```

The result will be a sorted array of all integer values AND their indices.
You can then iterate over those:

```
for each ( var n:Object in sortedArray) {
    doSomethingWith (n.value);
}

sortedArray.sortOn ("index", Array.NUMERIC);

for ( var i:int = sortedArray.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    _myArray.splice (sortedArray[i].index,1);
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something here but I don't think this will work. After doing `_myArray.splice(n.index, 1);` your _sortedArray_ has to recalculated or else the indexes will be (most probably) outdated/wrong.

Comment: You are right, of course. To my defense: I was very tired when I wrote this ;)  I have changed the code above,

Comment: Much better =) The important thing here is that the _myArray_ cannot be updated (add/edit/remove) during the _doSomething()_ call, otherwise the indexes would be messed up again. It all depends on the requirements now...

Comment: You could probably use `while (_myArray.length > 0)` to iterate and sort on each iteration, calling `splice (sortedArray[0].index,1)`.  Since Array.sort is a compiler optimized method, it might still be faster, depending on the size of the array and how many parsing steps are needed between values.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if you cannot sort the Array then there isn't much you can do to improve the algorithms performance. Any available solution will have to always loop through each item in the array, which means no performance gain. Even if you used an auxiliary mapper (or a duplicated sorted array) you would have to recalculate it every time a change was made on the primary array...not good!

I think that you have something like this:

```
 private function getNext(array:Array, value:Number):Number {
     var higher:Number = Number.MAX_VALUE;
     var position:Number = NaN;
     for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         if (!(array[i] is Number)) {
            continue;
         }
         var currentNumber:Number = array[i];
         if (currentNumber >= value && currentNumber < higher) {
            higher = currentNumber;
            position = i;
         }
     }
     return position;
  }
```

Usage:

```
getNext(myArray, 8);
```

Comment: Sorting will always be faster than this, unless you want to do it only once.  Even if you would implement your own sorting algorithm, it would sort the entire array just once, and after that you could simply get the entry at the next highest index.

Comment: I actually tried parsing an entire array with both your solution and mine. I took a longer _myArray = `[ 1, "pizza", 2, 6, 8, "test", 11, 16, 17, "cola", 3, "hamburger", 3,5,4,9,12,10,15,13,14,19,18, "fries" ];`. As you can see, lower numbers here could be at a later index than higher numbers (no sequential order). Not only does my solution take only half the time to finish (2ms compared to 4ms), yours also returns 0 for every String value in the array.  One more advantage would be using Array.UNIQUE when sorting, to prevent double results.

Comment: This is a generic solution, in order to get an optimized solution you have to make some assumptions. The question doesn't specify the requirements neither the operations/algorithm related to _myArray_ manipulation. For example, if the algorithm (your `doSomething()`) relies on the current _myArray_'s state then your solution will not work (unless you adapt it). Without this kind of information it's hard to find the ideal solution ;)

Comment: I agree ;)  Though there is a more general approach in my last comment to the other answer